# How to delete appscript from spreadsheet made by [other users]?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a public spreadsheet, some users added some script which I can't delete though owners' A/C.
From Scripts **File menu**> there is no 'Delete' option. I'm sharing screenshot of options available for my case (LogIn via owner A/C).

[image]

So, How to delete those scripts from my spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a script file by clicking on the grey downward facing arrow to the right of the file's name. File will by "something.gs", located in the top right hand corner underneath the back arrow.