# How to delete google script project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I have a number of obselete/empty projects on google I would like to delete.

I created the projects, so should be the owner. However when I go to **File** menu there is no "Delete project" option.

Any ideas how to remove the projects from the script editor list?

See screenshot of menu
[image]

Comment: If it's a bound script (attached to a spreadsheet or document), deleting the sheet or doc will also delete the project. Remember to empty the trash, too. You can also go to your [Google connected apps](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) permissions and remove them as necessary.

Comment: Are you in the script editor? That's where the delete project is.

Comment: The script is attached to a spreadsheet. But the spreadsheet is in use so I don't want to delete that. I looked into google connected apps permissions but it just gives the option to remove access. If I do this, will I then not have permission to delete them? @ Brian

Comment: Yeah, the drop down menu as attached above is in the script editor @Cooper

Comment: In the script editor you can select any project you wish then you can delete projects in the script editor. Deleting projects does not delete the spreadsheet

Comment: Hi @Cooper . If you open the screen shot attachment in the original question, it shows that there is no "delete project" option in the script editor file menu.

Comment: Related: [How to delete appscript from spreadsheet made by \[other users\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21092769/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Bounded scripts inherit sharing settings from the parent file, so the owner of the script is the owner of the file.

Only the owner of the file is able to delete a bounded script project.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating

Comment: strange as I have been able to delete some of the projects on the same file, but not all